# php - simpleXML how to access a specific element with the same name as others?

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<contact:addr>
  <contact:street></contact:street>
  <contact:street></contact:street>
  <contact:street></contact:street>
  <contact:city></contact:city>
  <contact:pc></contact:pc>
  <contact:cc></contact:cc>
</contact:addr>
```

On the example above we can see that we do have three times the element street;
Is there a way, by using simpleXML, to properly access, for example, the second street element?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element reference in SimpleXML can be accessed as an array (since it is an iterator), meaning that `$root->element[1]` will return the second element with name "element" under the root. (and `[0]` will return the first, as shown in the [SimpleXML examples](http://no.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) in the PHP manual.)

You can iterate over all the elements using `foreach($root->element as ..)`

Comment: @Gordon: Sir with 32135 reputation... I do believe that THAT is a tricky comment. I will have a look into the above. @fiskfisk thanks for the relation between the fact SimpleXML and iterator. ;) Really appreciated.

Comment: @Gordon: I do have something like this: $xmlObj->command->create->children(self::OBJ_URI_CONTACT)->create->postalInfo->addr->street and it works with the namespaces. Will not: $xmlObj->command->create->children(self::OBJ_URI_CONTACT)->create->postalInfo->addr->street[0] work ?

Comment: @all - for my previous question - a boolean answer may suffice. :)

Comment: @MEM It should work this way, but I found SimpleXml to be quirky when it comes to namespace support, though I hear it has been greatly improved with recent versions of PHP. Just give it a try.

Comment: @Gordon - Tested. Worked perfectly. ;) Yeah! :D Cheers.