# Multiple elements with the same name with SimpleXML and Java

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to use SimpleXML to parse an XML document (an `ItemLookupResponse` for a book from the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/)) which contains the following element:

```
<ItemAttributes>
  <Author>Shane Conder</Author>
  <Author>Lauren Darcey</Author>
  <Manufacturer>Pearson Educacion</Manufacturer>
  <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
  <Title>Android Wireless Application Development: Barnes & Noble Special Edition</Title>
</ItemAttributes>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to deal with the multiple possible `Author` elements.

Here's what I have right now for the corresponding POJO (Plain Old Java Object), keeping in mind that it's not handling the case of multiple `Author`s:

```
@Element
public class ItemAttributes {
    @Element
    public String Author;

    @Element
    public String Manufacturer;

    @Element
    public String Title;
}
```

(I don't care about the `ProductGroup`, so it's not in the class -- I'm just setting SimpleXML's `strict` mode to `off` to allow for that.)

I couldn't find an example in [the documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) that corresponded with such a case. Using an `ElementList` with `(inline=true)` seemed along the right lines, but I didn't see how to do it for String (as opposed to a separate Author class, which I have no need for and don't see how it would even work).

Here's a similar question and answer, but for PHP: [php - simpleXML how to access a specific element with the same name as others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652683/php-simplexml-how-to-access-a-specific-element-with-the-same-name-as-others) I don't know what the Java equivalent would be to the accepted answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N.B, this is just from reading the docs (the only question is if it should be name="Author" or entry="Author"):

```
@Element
public class ItemAttributes {
    @Element(inline=true, type=String.class, name="Author")
    public List<String> authors;
...
}
```